# Designing a web control with several controls, all programmably editable

Tags: asp.net

I need to design a web control which includes a poll, but also some images (image controls).

If I add the image controls to the web control, how can I edit these image controls? I need a web control with polls and images but the ability to edit the source of the image through properties (e.g. WebControl1.Image1.source = "";).

Thanks

Comment: Can you check your post again, I am not understanding what you really want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for the control inside the page.controls collection or in the {panelname}.controls or you can create a repeater.

Code example:

```
        For Each ctrl As Control In PollPanel.Controls
            If TypeOf ctrl Is Image Then
                Dim im As Image = CType(ctrl, Image)
                '...do stuff
            End If
        Next
```